# how to add padding to java swt groups

Tags: java, user-interface, swt

I am working on java swt. I wanted to add padding inside a group and I have tried as shown below.

```
    excelFileGroup = factory.createGroup(container, "Destination");
    FormLayout excelFileGroupLayout = new FormLayout();
    excelFileGroupLayout.marginBottom = 50;
    excelFileGroupLayout.marginTop = 10;
    excelFileGroupLayout.marginLeft = 10;
    excelFileGroupLayout.marginRight = 10;
    excelFileGroup.setLayout(excelFileGroupLayout);
```

Even after trying this I get no padding. Is there any other way or I have just used it in improper way.

Should I add padding in the LayoutData. If so then how?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You need to show us a more complete example of what you are doing

Comment: I want to add padding inside a Group

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear exactly what you are asking for or what your specific requirements are, but I am able to getting padding around the contents of a group using the following:

```
import org.eclipse.swt.SWT;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.Color;
import org.eclipse.swt.graphics.RGB;
import org.eclipse.swt.layout.FillLayout;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Composite;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Group;
import org.eclipse.swt.widgets.Shell;

public class GroupPadding extends Composite
{
  public GroupPadding(Shell parent, int style)
  {
    super(parent, style);
    this.setLayout(new FillLayout());

    // Group color (white)
    Color groupColor = new Color(parent.getDisplay(), new RGB(255, 255, 255));

    // Group content color (grey)
    Color groupContentColor = new Color(parent.getDisplay(), new RGB(100, 100, 100));

    Group g = new Group(this, SWT.NONE);
    g.setText("My group");
    FillLayout fl = new FillLayout();
    fl.marginHeight = 20;
    fl.marginWidth = 20;
    g.setLayout(fl);
    g.setBackground(groupColor);

    Composite c = new Composite(g, SWT.NONE);
    c.setBackground(groupContentColor);
  }

}
```

Which results in:

[image]